# How do I create a biased random number generator?

Tags: r, random

I need to create a random number generator that biases the selection of certain value classes over others. For example:

If I tell it to return a value between 1 and 5, unbiased would assign a 20% probability to each. But what if I wanted 2 and 3 to have a probabilities of 30% each, with the others down weighted accordingly.

How might I go about doing this in R with a range of 1-16 without restricting the output to an integer?<-- problem solved by Keegan below. The code below uses a modification of it for now, but that method is what I will run with in the end.

**New issue:When I run the walk it has 2 problems:**

**1) it always returns the same path (it's supposed to be random and therefore highly unlikely to ever give the same path twice).**

**2) if you run walkW(s) again it fails, saying that the XY coordinates no longer exist.** This wasn't an issue before I changed the sample pool to UBstep and Bstep, but I'm failing to see how and why this happened or how to fix it.

I've provided the core code before. You'll need a binary image in your working directory labeled "testmap2.png" as well as the EBImage package to run it.

To generate the error: run the entire code once, then run line walkW(s) again

Thanks in advance!

```
library("EBImage")

#calculating Z
P<-95 #dont worry about it
step.max<-125 #number of steps allowed to walk
stride<-131 #maximum pixel distance covered per step. 
s<-step.max

#step size pool
UBstep<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
Bstep<-c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)

#bring in a background image
pic<-readImage("testmap2.png",all=TRUE,package="EBImage")
rpic<-as.raster(pic)


#start walking
walkW <- function(n.times=125,
               xlim=c(0,615),
               ylim=c(0,615),
               start=c(520,100),
               stepsize=c(stride,stride)) {

    plot(c(0,0),type="n",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,
           xlab="x",
           ylab="y",
    col="black",col.lab="black")
lim <- par()
rasterImage(rpic, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])

    x <- start[1]
    y <- start[2]
    steps <- 1/sample(UBstep,1)
    Bsteps<-sample(Bstep,1)
    steps.y <- c(steps,-steps,0)
    steps.x <- c(steps[Bsteps],-steps,0)
    points(x,y,pch=16,col="green",cex=1)

for (i in 1:n.times) {
        repeat {
           xi <- stepsize[1]*sample(steps.x,1)
           yi <- stepsize[2]*sample(steps.y,1)
           newx <- x+xi
           newy <- y+yi
           if (newx>xlim[1] && newx<xlim[2] &&
               newy>ylim[1] && newy<ylim[2]) break
        }
        lines(c(x,newx),c(y,newy),col="cyan")
        x <- newx
        y <- newy

##dont worry about this function. It calculates z which is compared to the predefined P.
step.prob<-function(n.times=step.max){
CS<-pic[x,y,1]
CS.max<-1
step.num<-i
SP<-(((CS/CS.max)*(1-(step.num/step.max))+(step.num/step.max))*100)
}
z<-step.prob(1)

#draw lines and dots to make it pretty
if(z>P){points(newx,newy,pch=9,col="white",cex=1)}
if(z>P)break

if(i<step.max){points(newx,newy,pch="*",col="yellow",cex=1)}

}


}

set.seed(101)

walkW(s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `prob` argument to `sample`, you can set the weights however you like.

```
sample(1:5,prob=c(.05,.05,.1,.4,.4))
```

To draw one number from this distribution:

```
sample(1:5,1,prob=c(.05,.05,.1,.4,.4))
```

To draw many:

```
sample(1:5,50,prob=c(.05,.05,.1,.4,.4),replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Okay... so I put that argument in as the draw pool for a step size multiplier in my random walk model and now I'm getting an error from a section that worked before. Off hand can you think of a reason why this might have happened or should I start a new thread?

Comment: Hard to say without further information. Just make sure that the output of `sample` is the kind of thing you were expecting in the rest of your code.

Comment: ya I mean it's providing me with a single value output when invoked, so I'm really at a loss as to why it's now causing an error down stream... especially in an argument that doesn't really have much to do with it. I'll open a new line of inquiry. Thanks for all your help Keegan, you answered the question posed here quite well. Cheers

Comment: yes the community freaked out and started down-voting like crazy so I closed it. I'll update here.

Comment: I used this method to draw white ball and powerball based on powerball frequency since 1/18/12... On my first try two of the white ball numbers match tonight's winning numbers. I am using R instead of my own intuition next time.